# Optimal Way to solve a pandas dataframe percentage calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe DF1:

```
ID       Name     Rank
1        A        .99
2        B        .8
3        C        .8
```

And another dataframe DF2:

```
ID       Name     Rank
4        D        .999
2        B        .8
3        C        .8
8        H        .79
10       J        .78
11       K        .75      
30       AA       .7
50       CB       .6
6        F        .5 
7        G        .4
```

I want to know how much of DF1 is in the top 20 percentile in DF2.

So the top 20 percentile in DF2 is the first two rows since we only have 10 rows in this simple example. Since only B is in the 20th percentile, then only 1 row out of 3 is there, so the answer would be 33.33%

I know I can use `.isin()` to see how many in the exist in the other. But I'm clueless about the rest. I don't want to resort to looping as I have thousand of different DFs I need to compare and extract the percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking about the 20th percentile of the Rank column in DF2 then I believe C would be included also.

However, you can take the follow code and modify if needed.

```
df2_20 = df2[df2.Rank >= df2.Rank.quantile(q=.8)]
df1.isin(df2_20).all(1).mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

use `quantile` + `>` + `mean`

```
DF1.Rank.gt(DF2.Rank.quantile(.8)).mean()

0.33333333333333331
```

Comment: it will be a better answer if you please describe it.